# Passing objects vs. Singleton

Tags: oop, singleton

As far as I can see there are two main principles how to deal with application-wide role player objects like a root model object (in MVC context):

1. create the object and pass it through the object tree (e.g. in the constructor)
2. provide it as a singleton or other global variable technique

The first approach seems to be cleaner because the dependencies are better visible but there is a lot of additional work to do (parameters, class variables,...).

What do you prefer?

**Edit:** The first technique also uses only one instance but it is provided by passing the object and not by a static function

Comment: A lot depends on what kind of object it is... One aspect that should be considered when dealing with singletons is testability (use interfaces + concrete implementations for them.)

Comment: Lets assume it's the applications main model object where all other model objects come together.

Comment: Hmm... If you stick to the MVC/MVP pattern, then you definitely want to have your model passed into the View component. Other than that, I have no ready answer. Having a non-singleton model will let you swap it on the fly if need be, that's one related thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer run singletons' method `getInstance()` as constructor parameter - bake two birds with one stone ;)

Comment: Awesome! The simplicity of a Singleton without missing a clear interface. Very flexible approach, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is where dependency injection can help out.  Having to explicitly pass all the correct dependencies manually to an object whenever you create one can be a pain and perhaps somewhat error prone.  A decent dependency injection container can help to automate this process and is actually easier to use than singletons.

The Symfony2 framework is a modern example:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 0):

I think passing as parameter is a little more memory-efficient, easier to debug, but need a some additional work.

I prefer to use singletons only when i really need it (like database sessions, write to file etc.).

It really depends on project type, language, budget, size of project etc. There is no "universal" answer.